# Magento 2 catalog search not working when letters combine with numbers

Tags: product, magento2.3, catalog, search, catalogsearch

Magento 2.3.5-p1 version

Suppose the product name is "Super M2" when we search "m2" then it is not showing results on the search page

but when the product name is "Super M21" when we search "m21" then it is showing results on search page.

Can anyone know how to solve these issues?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to the setting Minimum search query length (Default is 3 I think). This is found under Catalog -> Catalog -> Catalog Search.

Comment: i already put there 2(replace with 3)